# Mongo lookup returning all values

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-lookup

I have 2 collections as shown below:

```
branches
{
  _id: ..., 
  custId: "abc123",
  branchCode: "AA",
...other fields
}

branchHolidays
{
  _id: ..., 
  custId: "abc123", 
  holidayDate: ISODate("2019-06-01T00:00:00:0000"),
  holidayStatus: "PROCESSED",
..other fields
}
```

Need to get all **branchHolidays** with the custId available in **branches** collection along with the branchCode from **branches** collection. (branches.custId = branchHolidays.custId)

For the first part of join I tried the below query but I'm getting all the fields from **branchHolidays** collection.

```
db.getCollection('branchHolidays').aggregate([
{
  $lookup: {
    localField: "custId",
    from: "branches",
    foreignField: "custId",
    as: "holidays"
  }
},
$match: {  holidayStatus: "PROCESSED" }
])
```

The above query returns all the documents from **branchHolidays** collection. 
I'm new to mongo but I'm not able to figure out what the problem is. Have gone through most of the SO queries but haven't found anything which helped.

Note: There are multiple branchCodes mapped to 1 custId in **branches** collection.

Comment: Not totally clear on what you are trying to do.  Since you are aggregating on `branchHolidays` and only filtering by `holidayStatus: "PROCESSED"`, you should be getting all documents in `branchHolidays` except those that are not tagged `PROCESSED`.  Were you intending to do an additional filter based on the `$lookup` result?

Comment: Shouldn't it be giving me only those documents where the branchHolidays.custId = branches.custId? Instead it's giving me all documents even if the custId is not present in branches collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$lookup` stage is similar to a left outer join.  The sample aggregation should return all documents from the `branchHolidays` collection that have `holidayStatus: "PROCESSED"`, and each document will have an added field `holidays` containing all documents from the `branches` collection that have the same `custId`.  For those documents that do not match any braches, the `holidays` field will contain an empty array.

If you want to return only document that have matching branches, match on size, like:

```
  holidays:{$not:{$size:0}}
```

Also note placing the `$match: {  holidayStatus: "PROCESSED" }` before the `$lookup` will avoid querying the branches collection for documents that would be eliminated, which may improve performance.